# Can we overload = (assignment operator) in swift?

Tags: swift, operator-overloading

i need to override assignment operator in swift = but unfortunately i am no success at that. I have gone through many articles but they just conclude that to overload = in swift is not possible!

Kindly share if there is any way to achieve that.

Thanks in advance. Happy coding.

Comment: Those articles that you read are correct: You simply can't override the assignment operator.

Comment: is there any workaround ?

Comment: The linked-to Q&A has a reference to the documentation which clearly states that `=` cannot be overloaded. What kind of “workaround” are you thinking of?

Comment: As a work around you could define your own operator e.g. `func *=*<T, U>(target: inout T, source: U) { target = castUToTSomehow(source) }` However, if you explain why you need the override, perhaps we can provide a less horrible way of doing it.